# Create a HashMap with JsonObject as the key

Tags: java, gson

I have a `HashMap<JsonObject, Integer>`, where `JsonObject` belongs to Google's `gson` library.

I have noticed that if you put an entry, and then modify the `JsonObject` key (like add members or something), you won't be able to get the entry's value using the same key. I suspect it is because the `hashcode` of the `JsonObject` changes when you change its members.

I'm not sure whether this is the expected behavior here, but if it is, then I'm curious about any workarounds to this: I want to create a `HashMap` where `JsonObject` is the key.

Comment: Don't use mutable types as keys for maps. Or make sure you don't mutate them. Your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What you think is correct. Only one thing is strict that the key that you're pushing should not be mutable other wise that same key may not be retrieved. So you need to ensure that.
  Or `IdentityHashMap` might come to your rescue since equality condition is based on `==` check and not `equals()`.
And since you tell that hashCode changes, I think that is the responsibility of the map to distribute your objects well. You can think about it later with performance aspects.